# How to figure out xpath for IMPORTXML in Google Sheets - Receiving An Error

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

Thank you guys in advance for your attention

I'm trying to use the IMPORTXML function on Google Sheets.

For example:=IMPORTXML("https://mg.olx.com.br/belo-horizonte-e-regiao/videogames/xbox-one-controle-hd-externo-975535277, XMLPATH) should return "(31) 98749-2542", which is the complete phone number. Although it has a "login wall" in order to access the complete number, I can see the full number directly on the page source code.

Firefox xPath Finder extension gives me:

/html/body/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPSHu.jpg)/div/div[4]/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPSHu.jpg)/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPSHu.jpg)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPSHu.jpg)/div[9]/div/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPSHu.jpg)/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/a/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPSHu.jpg)

When I try this in Google Sheets it returns an error: #N/A (Import Content is Empty).

Please see the attachment image to see what excatly im looking for.[image]

[full number on source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPSHu.jpg)

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(importxml(A1,"//script[@id='initial-data']/@data-json"),"(\d+)"",""phoneHidden")
```

### Explanation

XPATH is here `//script[@id='initial-data']/@data-json` and will give you the script that contains all data included in a json

Then use regular expression to fetch the number before phoneHidden
[image]

Comment: Hi Mike, how are you? Thank you very very much! I find your formula works well in 90% of cases. In some pages it does not retrieve the number but gives me a "3000" number instead. 

This happens in this url for example
https://mg.olx.com.br/belo-horizonte-e-regiao/videogames/xbox-one-com-9-jogos-aceito-cartao-e-parcelo-978472849

https://mg.olx.com.br/belo-horizonte-e-regiao/videogames/xbox-one-500gb-com-garantia-978722349

what may be happen in this cases? maybe another expression is needeed?

Comment: ok, I have a bit amended my proposal

Comment: Steelson oh sorry! didnt know this feature.. thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

From your following provided image,

[image]

it seems that the value you want to retrieve is in a JSON object. And, fortunately, the HTML data includes the JSON data. In this case, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose using Google Apps Script. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and save the script.

```js
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const str = res.getContentText().match(/data-json\="(.+?)">/);
  if (str && str.length == 2) {
    const convert = [{from: "&quot;", to: '"'}, {from: "&gt;", to: ">"}, {from: "&lt;", to: "<"}, {from: "&#39;", to: "'"}, {from: "&amp;", to: "&"}];
    const o = JSON.parse(convert.reduce((s, {from, to}) => s.replace(new RegExp(from, "g"), to), str[1]));
    return o.ad && o.ad.phone && o.ad.phone.phone ? o.ad.phone.phone : "Value couldn't be found.";
  }
  return "Value couldn't be found.";
}
```

#### Testing:

Please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE("https://mg.olx.com.br/belo-horizonte-e-regiao/videogames/xbox-one-controle-hd-externo-975535277")` to a cell. By this, `31987492542` is returned.

#### Note:

- This sample script can be used for the current HTML data of the URL of `https://mg.olx.com.br/belo-horizonte-e-regiao/videogames/xbox-one-controle-hd-externo-975535277`. When the specification of the site is changed and the HTML data is changed, this script might not be able to be used. So please be careful about this.
- This sample script is for the current URL of `https://mg.olx.com.br/belo-horizonte-e-regiao/videogames/xbox-one-controle-hd-externo-975535277`. So when you change the URL, this script might not be able to be used. So please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)
- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Tainake how are you? it workd perfectly thank you so much! If it is not asking too much, do you think is it possible to use the same script approach to scrap the product value number?  Using the same URL example you took, it would extract the value 1200.

Comment: @Ramon Miranda Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `If it is not asking too much, do you think is it possible to use the same script approach to scrap the product value number? Using the same URL example you took, it would extract the value 1200.`, my proposed script is for your URL of `https://mg.olx.com.br/belo-horizonte-e-regiao/videogames/xbox-one-controle-hd-externo-975535277`. So when the URL is changed, this script might not be able to be used as I have already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Ramon Miranda In that case, it is required to modify the script. I deeply apologize that I cannot propose a script for using all URLs you want to use. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindess and wish you all good things... hugs from Brazil! see you